# Aurelia bundle all jspm dependencies automatically

Tags: gulp, aurelia, jspm

I'm trying to automatically bundle all jspm dependencies --so I don't have to maintain a manual list-- with a gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');
var package = require('../../package.json');

var jspmDeps = Object.keys(package.jspm.dependencies);

var config = {
    force: true,
    baseURL: '.',
    configPath: './system.config.js',
    bundles: {
        "output/jspm": {
            "includes": jspmDeps,
            "options": {
                "minify": false,
                "inject" : true
            }
        }
    }
};

gulp.task('build-jspm', function () {
    return bundler.bundle(config);
});
```

Unfortunately, this isn't picking up and bundling all sub-dependencies of the modules included in the bundle. Quite a few dependencies are dynamically loaded by aurelia, which don't get detected during bundling.

Is there a way to force aurelia-bundler (or jspm-cli) to bundle the entire dependency tree from jspm?

**[Update]** Turns out jspm's bundler [has the same behavior](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1814#issuecomment-219566216), in that it won't bundle modules unless it detects a call to `import 'some-sub-dependency'`; [there are plans to trace dynamic loading at some point](https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/452)